# Admin control in C# giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm writing a control to add a button to edit my pages. The control is named adminlinks and it contains a link that should only be visible to the role admin. Any Ideas on why i'm getting the error invalid token with this script? Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.UserControl;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;

public partial class Controls_adminlinks : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e);

if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    uc1:adminlinks.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    uc1:adminlinks.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: which line gives you the error?

Comment: This LIne:if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        uc1:adminlinks.Visible = true;
    }
    else

Comment: but does it fail at the `if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))` or at the `uc1:adminlinks.Visible = true;`

Comment: Apologies if fails at the if

Comment: It states: invalid token "if" in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 0):

You need a method.

Your if statement is in the class and not a method.  For example:

```
    public void TestMethod()
    {
          if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
           {
             uc1:adminlinks.Visible = true;
            }
          else
         {
           uc1:adminlinks.Visible = false;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you issue is that the code is not containted in you Page_Load function.  You have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e);
```

But it should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){ 

    if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        uc1:adminlinks.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        uc1:adminlinks.Visible = false;
    }
}
```